# Tabs don't get removed from string

Tags: java

Environment : Windows, Java 1.8
I am reading the content of a file and I try to format the lines and remove the tabs, but `replaceAll` it's not working.

I tryed with:

```
    BufferedReader bf = FileUtils.getBufferedReader(filePath);
    String line;

    try {
        while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null )
        {
            if(line.matches(".*=.*"))
            {
                // this is a simple test scenario
                String test = "\tVERSION=version";
                test.trim();
                test.replaceAll("\t", "");

                line.trim();
                line.replaceAll("\\t", "");

            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("[ERROR] : Could not read from file <" + filePath + ">!\n");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

I looked into debugger and the tabs are not replaced. On the test scenario I tried with both `\t` and `\\t` variants without success. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: how about reassigning the `String`, remember `String`'s are immutable.

Comment: Try `test = test.replaceAll(...)` etc., just as some java guy suggested ;)

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy Yup, that was the problem

Comment: @Thomas As some java guy suggested, immutable because object ..

Comment: I know what he suggested but I don't quite get what you mean by "immutable because object " ;) - objects are not immutable by default but strings (which are objects) are as well as other classes like `Integer`, `Date` etc.

Comment: @Thomas My bad, what I wanted to write was constants :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, a String is immutable - that means you can not change a string, so a method such as String.replaceAll could never change the String object you call that method on.

As noted in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--), both String.trim() and String.replaceAll() returns a new, altered, string. That's the string you need to use, and forget about the old string. Your code should look like:

```
test =  test.trim();
test =  test.replaceAll("\t", "");

line = line.trim();
line = line.replaceAll("\\t", "");
```

Comment: That did it, thanks a lot! I guess that introduction into variables from every tutorial has it's own importance...